# Cannot generate migrations on rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used to work with rails 2.3.2 before and then I decided to upgrade to version 2.3.4.

Today I tried to generate a migration(I could do this fine with version 2.3.2) and I got the following error message:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:812:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport (NameError)
        from D:/Proyectos/Cursometro/www/config/environment.rb:33
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:111:in `run'
        from D:/Proyectos/Cursometro/www/config/environment.rb:15
        from D:/Proyectos/Cursometro/www/config/environment.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/generate.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from script\generate:3
```

I don't know why this is happening. Everything worked fine in 2.3.2 and now it doesn't.

Comment: I have always had problems migrating from one version of rails using Netbeans. Btw, are you working on the Ruby or Jruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could solve this by placing the following line(written below) once the `Rails::Initializer.run do |config|` block ends(it was inside this block before).

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:standard => "%B %d, %Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Activesupport gem is not installed on your machine. Try running this command:

```
gem install activesupport
```

Incase it doesn't work, try this

```
gem update --system
gem update --source http://gems.rubyonrails.org
```

Comment: Snehal: neither of those options worked. I'm getting the same error. I'll give you a vote for the try.